# Can we use 9patch images with html5 mobile designing

Tags: android, html, android-layout, nine-patch

I am a native android developer. In designing part 9patch is quite useful to me. Problem is I need to know whether I can use 9patch images in html5 android applications? If I use them in do they stretch as it does in android (native) applications? Apart from, that is it ok with other platforms of html5 applications (I mean blackberry, windows, iPhone and etc). I use phone-gap to create other versions.

`https://github.com/chrislondon/9-Patch-Image-for-Websites` answer is ok but problem is I have to do some work around to over come this. Isn't there any better option? This is big issue to decide whether I go for html5 or native applications.

Comment: Seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659457/nine-patch-images-for-web-development same question

Comment: please check my updated answere